# Pie chart labels - dynamic position (distance)

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to get some datalabels showing inside segments of a doughnut chart where there is suitable space to do so.

I know I can use negative `distance` values on the the data labels config options, but I wonder how I can achieve this dynamically based on the values\size of the segments.

Is such a technique achievable? Can I have a mix of data labels outside of the segments connected with lines (connectors) and others inside the actual segments?

My starting point so far based off the official highcharts example pie chart code: https://jsfiddle.net/parky12/tbnjypse/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use `chart.load` event and change `distance`, `x` or `y` properties for an individual point. For example:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    this.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
      if (point.y > 5) {
        point.update({
          dataLabels: {
            distance: -50
          }
          // avoid redraw after each update
        }, false);
      }
    });
    this.redraw();
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lco29fdj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update